# How to allow output onto webpage from console log mqtt message

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, mqtt

A few questions and I apologise if they seem unprofessional, I am a beginner programmer. But I would really appreciate any and all help you'd provide!

1. Currently, I have used an MQTT program to receive messages over websockets. I can view my message in the console.log but I would like to ask how can I convert it to the html output messages. is it by document.getElementById ? or is there a more better way to do that?
2. What is the benefit of using JSON for the messages?
3. What is the purpose of using variable.push(entry.anothervariable) is the push entry better and perhaps I should use an array to store the messages and then push them out?

Thank you!

Comment: None of this is specific to MQTT, it's all just general working with the HTML DOM from JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks hardillb, I do have one more question, if the mqtt message lets say is message.payloadString and theres several messages, if I would use the get element would I be able to get all of the messages or would I need to create an array and save them somehow to be able to output all the messages?

Comment: As I said in my answer we have absolutely no context for these questions, we can only guess. You need to include a LOT more information in your questions.

Comment: No worries, I managed to get it working. It was super simple!

Answer (score 0):

Without context answering these questions are not really a good fit for Stackoverflow, but here are some answers.

1. Without the context of what frameworks you are using, yes finding an element with `document.getElementById()` and then updating it's content with `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` is probably the simiplest way forward
2. Sending messages encoded as JSON when working with JavaScript means that you don't need to worry about parsing any other encoding format, you can directly access fields using the native JavaScript Object Model.
3. This question is totally unanswerable with out any context for what you are actually working with. The `.push()` method is how you append an item to an existing array.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. They honestly did help and did point to the right direction. I appreciate your contribution hardillb!